# Launch the same activity and then go up. How to preserve intent params?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm launching the same `ArticleActivity` from `ArticleAtivity` with different EXTRA param

```
Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ArticleActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(ArticleActivity.INTENT_EXTRA_ARTICLE_ID, articleId);
view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Articles can have subarticles. I use `artileId` from intent to fetch it's contents and subarticles. So I can go deep like this:
`A > A > A > A`

Then I need to go up. Like this:
`A > A > A > A < upBtn < upBtn < upBtn`
Trying to use the standrad toolbar up button.
But it returns me to the first screen.
I do not need `launchMode="singleTop"` since I want user to be able to go back level by level and at least keep id of the article to feth for each level.

I tried to do something with `savedInstanceState`, but when I press up button `savedInstancedState` is always null in `onCreate` and activity is recreated from scrath.

So I need to pass `articleId` when I press up button somehow.
How would I do that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **best way** to do this is to just **call a method** within that `activity` **and update the details**. Upon updating, save the `articleId` to an `ArrayList` then handle the `onBackPressed()` to pop the last `articleId` until it goes back.

```
private ArrayList<Integer> articleIds = new ArrayList<>(); //initialize on top
```

Then instead of calling the `activity` again, call method just to refresh for the new details, then save the new `articleId`:

```
initDetails(int articleId) {
   articleIds.add(articleId);

   //load the new detail with the new article Id...
}
```

And on the `onBackPressed()`, here's  the logic how you will go back on the past `articleIds` you've used:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!articleIds.isEmpty()) { //check if there's still articleId left to load
        initDetails(articleIds.get(articleIds.size() - 1)); //call the init details again with the previous articleId

        articleIds.remove(articleIds.size() - 1); //remove the last ID
    } else {  //call here if this is the last articleId
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

If there's something I've missed out to explain or if there's something is confusing, don't hesitate to tell me.

Comment: So it's basically not to start any new ArticleActivities and refresh data in the same instance? @tenten-ponce

Comment: Yes, and I think it is much expensive to launch new activity instead of just refreshing the details needed to be refreshed.

Comment: Thank you! I've reorginized my code and it works like a charm. Don't know why I haven't thought about it first place )